# How to fetch output data from storedprocedure into Jtextfeild

Tags: java

```
try { conn = inventconnect.ConnecrDb();

        stored_pro = conn.prepareCall("{call generateentry(?)}");
        stored_pro.setString(1, this.txt_userrinfo.getText());
        stored_pro.execute();
        while (rs.next()) {
       String add1 = stored_pro.getString("entry_id");
            jTextField1.setText(add1);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);

    }
```

i hava procedure which inserts user and outputs an auto generated entryid as below

create procedure generateentry(
@user_name nvarchar(50)
)
as begin
insert into entry_no (user_name,entry_type)
OUTPUT INSERTED.entry_id
values(@user_name,'po')
end

i need results on my procedure to be didplayed in my jtextField1 as in my code above when a button is preess. am getting a null pointer error but the database is effected though my textfeild is not displaying any results. please help

Comment: the values are inserted in the database but not displayed in my JtextField. i also get an error:parameter entry_id was not defined for procedure. please help am stuck

Comment: First, your procedure should return the afftected rows count.

Comment: the porcedure is working fine. it outputs the entry_id. my problem is to display the output in the jextfield as in the code above